# How to allow uiAccess in UWP application

Tags: c++, uwp, uac, microsoft-ui-automation

I am invoking C++ UIautomation modules in my UWP application. The application is not able to extract control elements since it is not running in an elevated environment. How should I set up the manifest file or set my UWP app to be able to get access to ui elements of other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you could put the UIautomation modules into a console app and then launch the console as elevated from your UWP app using desktop bridge. You will also need to add the [allowElevation capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities) into the manifest file.

For detailed steps, you could take a look at Stefan wick's blog- [App Elevation Samples](https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/07/app-elevation-samples-part-3/).

Comment: Thanks mate. I followed and talked with stefan regarding the issue. 
I was trying to run the console from the UWP app. However  , i was not able to do it for a C++/CX UWP app. ( I was able to do from a C# UWP app  and i followed the same procedure for C++). Is there any repository for a C++ UWP implementation of the same. It throws some dll issues and file not found errors when running FulltrustLaunch api through a C++ UWP application.